# Python: Count elements on Counter output

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a nested list as:

```
 List1 = [[A,B,A,A],[C,C,B,B],[A,C,B,B]]..... so on
```

I used counter function to count the number of elements in the nested lists:

```
for i,j in enumerate(List1):
    print(Counter(j))
```

I got following output as:

```
Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 1})
Counter({'C': 2, 'B': 2})
Counter({'B': 2, 'A': 1, 'C': 1})
....
```

I want to calculate percentage of A in Counter output:

```
A = number of A's / total number of elements
```

For example:

```
Counter({'A': 3, 'B': 1})
```

Would yield:

```
A = 3/4 = 0.75
```

I am not able to calculate A, Can anyone kindly help me with this?

Comment: `print (Counter(j)["A"]/float(len(j)))`

Comment: What happens if i do not know which element is in the sublist? For eg. If i do not know sublist has "A" and I still like percentage values for each element.

Comment: `A = number of A's / total number of elements` is misleading since your example shows a different output. did you mean `sum of elements` instead of `total number of elements`?

Comment: @Explore_SDN Please update your question with necessary details.

Comment: yes, it is sum of elements.c = Counter(j) s = sum(c.values()) print(c) print ( c.keys/ s) -> When I use this code for any character in sublist, I am not able to make this work. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would give you a list of dictionaries holding both the counts and the percentages for each entry:

```
List1 = [['A','B','A','A'],['C','C','B','B'],['A','C','B','B']]
counts = [Counter(x) for x in List1]
percentages = [{k : (v, v / float(len(l1))) for k,v in cc.items()} for l1, cc in zip(List1, counts)]

print percentages
```

Giving the following output:

```
[{'A': (3, 0.75), 'B': (1, 0.25)}, {'C': (2, 0.5), 'B': (2, 0.5)}, {'A': (1, 0.25), 'C': (1, 0.25), 'B': (2, 0.5)}]
```

For just the percentages:

```
List1 = [['A','B','A','A'],['C','C','B','B'],['A','C','B','B']]
counts = [Counter(x) for x in List1]
percentages = [{k : v / float(len(l1)) for k,v in cc.items()} for l1, cc in zip(List1, counts)]

print percentages
```

Giving:

```
[{'A': 0.75, 'B': 0.25}, {'C': 0.5, 'B': 0.5}, {'A': 0.25, 'C': 0.25, 'B': 0.5}]
```

Comment: I feel we can be more succinct `[{i: x.count(i)/float(len(x)) for i in x} for x in List1]` - check my answer? :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for sublist in List1:
        c = Counter(sublist)
        print(c['A'] / sum(c.values()))

0.75
0.0
0.25
```

---

All values at once:

```
>>> for sublist in List1:
        c = Counter(sublist)
        s = sum(c.values())
        print(c['A'] / s, c['B'] / s, c['C'] / s)

0.75 0.25 0.0
0.0 0.5 0.5
0.25 0.5 0.25
```

If you want to get a list of all items in a sublist with their respective percentages, you need to iterate the counter:

```
>>> for sublist in List1:
        c = Counter(sublist)
        s = sum(c.values())
        for elem, count in c.items():
            print(elem, count / s)
        print()

A 0.75
B 0.25

B 0.5
C 0.5

A 0.25
B 0.5
C 0.25
```

Or use a dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> for sublist in List1:
        c = Counter(sublist)
        s = sum(c.values())
        print({ elem: count / s for elem, count in c.items() })

{'A': 0.75, 'B': 0.25}
{'B': 0.5, 'C': 0.5}
{'A': 0.25, 'B': 0.5, 'C': 0.25}
```

Comment: What happens if i do not know which element is in the sublist? For eg. If i do not know sublist has "A" and I still like percentage values for each element.

Comment: Indexing an element of a counter that does not exist will yield 0, so it still works. You could do it as above for all of A, B, and C, and it would output the correct percentage.

Comment: c = Counter(j) s = sum(c.values()) print(c) print ( c.keys/ s) -> When I use this code for any character in sublist, I am not able to make this work. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
In [1]: l = [['A','B','A','A'],['C','C','B','B'],['A','C','B','B']]

In [2]: [{i: x.count(i)/float(len(x)) for i in x} for x in l]
Out[2]:
[{'A': 0.75, 'B': 0.25},
 {'B': 0.5, 'C': 0.5},
 {'A': 0.25, 'B': 0.5, 'C': 0.25}]
```

Comment: Now do this also for B and C, and you have the need for a counter.

Comment: What happens if i do not know which element is in the sublist? For eg. If i do not know sublist has "A" and I still like percentage values for each element.

Comment: c = Counter(j)
s = sum(c.values())
print(c)
print ( c.keys/ s) -> When I use this code for any character in sublist, I am not able to make this work. Can you tell me what is wrong?

Comment: @Explore_SDN See my updated answer, you can achieve what you want in a simple one liner

Answer (score 0):

You can use list generator and join method to connect your lists of lists of chars into one-liner list of strings.

```
>>> List1 = [['A', 'B', 'A', 'A'],['C', 'C', 'B', 'B'],['A', 'C', 'B', 'B']]
>>> [''.join(x) for x in List1]
['ABAA', 'CCBB', 'ACBB']
```

Then, join again your list to the one string.

```
>>> ''.join(['ABAA', 'CCBB', 'ACBB'])
'ABAACCBBACBB'
```

And count 'A' symbol, or any other.

```
>>> 'ABAACCBBACBB'.count('A')
4
```

This could be one-liner solution:

```
>>> ''.join(''.join(x) for x in List1).count('A')
4
```

String of symbols is iterable type. The same as the list. List of strings is more useful than the list of lists of chars.